# Python2.7.1 import OpenCV2.2 error Windows XP

Tags: python, windows-xp, opencv, importerror

I'm having some trouble using OpenCV2.2 with Python2.7.1 (which should be compatible). I've installed OpenCV to `D:\OpenCV2.2PreCom\`, added the `D:\OpenCV2.2PreCom\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages` path to `sys.path` as well as to the environment variable PYTHONPATH.

I've also made sure the `D:\OpenCV2.2PreCom\bin` path is added to the Path environment variable. However, when I try to access the `cv.pyd` file (which is in `D:\OpenCV2.2PreCom\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages\`) by typing 'import cv',

I get an `importerror`:

The IDLE looks like this:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('D:\OpenCV2.2PreCom\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages')
>>> import cv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

So what else can I try to make Python import OpenCV?

With kind regards.

Comment: This is not what's causing your problem, but I thought I'd mention it: always put Windows paths in raw strings: `r'C:\foo\bar'` to avoid escape sequences breaking stuff. In this case it doesn't matter because coincidentally none of the letters are valid escape sequences when preceded by \

Answer (score 0):

Not a Windows user, but seems that the Python module cannot find the DLL. It is not a problem of `PYTHONPATH`.

Did you install it or just unpack it? Try installing it with the installer, it should take care of positioning the DLL in the right path.

Comment: I don't think the Windows installer of OpenCV sets up the Python paths at all, actually. I've always just manually copied `OpenCV-2.2\Python2.7\Lib` into my Python installation's `Lib` and it's worked. (It only contains a `cv.pyd` file, which is the DLL in question)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try escaping the backslashes?  Try this:

```
>>>> sys.path.append('D:\\OpenCV2.2PreCom\\Python2.7\\Lib\\site-packages')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the content of `D:\OpenCV2.2PreCom\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages` (there should be two files inside ) in the site-packages of your python install, the default one being `C:\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages`  and escape you back lashes or replace them with `/`

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have solved the problem after restarting my computer. I'll remember to use the raw strings (r''), but in this case, that was not the problem. Still not sure why Python doesn't recognise the files when not in the default Lib folder though. Appending the a path to sys.path should make Python look for modules in that directory right?

Comment: I think that they are using the relative path to link to these files, that is why they are not found even when added to the PATH variable